# Apagar um ficheiro executável ( .exe ) após finalizar sem saber a sua localização?

Tags: windows, vba, script, batch

O ficheiro bat foi convertido em executável.
O comando `del "%~f0"` não funciona! Será necessário terminar a execução do executável primeiro `taskkill /f "nome_do_executável.exe"` e só depois o eliminar?

Questão:
- Como localizar o ficheiro no windows e o eliminar?

Desde já obrigado @SachaDee pelo `%~dpnx0`!

```
start "nome_da_aplicação" cmd.exe /k "mode 90,5 & del /s /q %~dpnx0 >nul 2>&1 & exit"
```

Comment: testou `del "%~dpnx0"`no final do script ?

Comment: @SachaDee sim, obrigado!

Comment: A onde posso encontrar informação sobre 'dpnx'?

Comment: com `for /?` (ultima tela)

Comment: @SachaDee, obrigado!

Comment: @SachaDee, O comando `del /s /q "%~dpnx0"` parece não estar a funcionar no executável... Mas se utilizar `start cmd /k  "del /s /q %~dpnx0"` funciona, só que uma nova janela é aberta! Como fechar essa janela num comando só? Ex: `start cmd /k  "del %~dpnx0 & exit /b"`?

Comment: executar taskkill pode fazer com que o Windows Defender exclua seu arquivo executável

Comment: @Sveen Como... assim? `taskkill /F /FI "WindowTitle eq  Administrator: nome_do_programa" /T >nul 2>&1 & del /s /q "%~dpnx0" & exit /b`?

Comment: Se utilizar `start cmd /k  "del %~dpnx0"` vai funcionar (mas depois fica uma linha de comandos aberta), só se terminar a linha de comandos com o taskkill! Parece-me um bocado martelado... Não existe a possibilidade em efetuar tudo junto dentro do `""`?

Comment: O Windows Defender verifica se o programa executa um comando como taskkill e classifica com malware.

Comment: Tente assim @b8engl : `start cmd /k "del %~dpnx0 && exit"`

Comment: @ SachaDee Bem jogado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar isso no final do script bat :

```
start cmd /k  "del %~dpnx0"
```